# Without disabling validation, how can I encode this .Input field containing the "<" and ">" signs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an input field in a form that accepts text from a user.  The user in question will always copy/paste in text from a auto-generated e-mail that includes "<" and ">" around text.  This will throw an error since the text will be recognized as HTML.  Without disabling validation (by ValidateInput(false)), how can I encode this .Input field my users can copy/paste the text with the "<" and ">" signs?

```
<%=Html.Input(sample => sample.SampleInput)%>
```

Comment: i don't know the mechanics of making it happen, but you want to html encode the input before sending it to the server.  this will convert the characters to their HTML entity equivalents: `&gt;` and `&lt;`

Comment: Do you mean that they'll copy and paste `<example@example.com>` and you want to ignore the `<` and `>` signs and get `example@example.com`, or e.g. `<example>@example.com` and the `<` and `>` signs are part of the address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute on your model property to allow HTML code to pass validation.

Please note that this is a possible security issue since the submitted input could contain scripting code.  This is why it's prohibited by default.  So take care of the input you receive to ensure it's safe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: This information will get redisplayed on another page.  Will using the [AllowHtml] attribute keep the text within the greater than or less than signs from displaying on that page?  I am considering changing the the "<" and ">" to "(" and ")" in the generated email that gets copy/pasted over.

Comment: The `AllowHtml` will do nothing about how the data is displayed later.  It only allows you to accept input including `<` and `>` characters.  It will not modify the input text in any way.  Whether the `<` and `>` characters hide the text between will depend on how that text is displayed back to the user.  You'll want to encode it when displaying it to the user:  `<` => `&lt;` and `>` => `&gt;`.

Comment: AllowHtml allows the controller to accept angle brackets. If you want to redisplay it on the page, you should encode it before you do so. You should always be doing this with user provided input anyway to avoid cross-site-scripting attacks. With asp.net 4 you can do `<%:Model.value%>` to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [New Request validation features in ASP.Net 4.5](http://weblogs.asp.net/sreejukg/archive/2011/12/20/new-request-validation-features-in-asp-net-4-5.aspx)

```
 <httpruntime requestvalidationmode="4.5" />
```

Or you can `[AllowHtml]` on your Model Object

```
public class User{

    [AllowHtml]
    public string email {get; set;}
}
```

Or you can just switch off validation for a single action if you like.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionMethod Edit(User user)
{
    // Do your own checking of value since `user` could contain XSS stuff!
    return View();
}
```